# Sublime Text 2: LaTeXTools reference completion using cref

Tags: cross-referencing

I am using sublime text 2 and LaTeXTools to write .tex files. In general this works fine.

However, I am using the cref package and changed the auto-completion (`ref_completion.py`) for references such that it recognizes cref.

All this worked fine until an update came. Now I am back to the old version despite having copied `ref_completion.py` to the user folder.

Apparently though, this only works for settings.

So here is my question: Is there a smart way (besides copying the old file back into the LaTeXTools folder after each update) to store my changes permanently?

Comment: I was just putting it here since it seems more like a sublime text 2 question (since it concerns the behaviour of the sublime engine rather than La(Tex) itself). Actually, I believe it carries over to some extend to other languages if coded in sublime tex rather than to other Latex editors. However, if you feel it belongs to TeX-LaTeX, just go ahead moving it over

Comment: If so, this might be more relevant in http://superuser.com/ . Let the moderators decide whether and where the question should be migrated.

Comment: Probably this should have been migrated to SuperUser, but the time is passed ('too old to migrate'). Ah well :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude packages from auto-upgrades:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Package Control/Package Control.sublime-settings
```

Around line 45:

```
"auto_upgrade_ignore": [],
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Somehow I do not believe this is the most elegant way though. As far as I understand the structure of Sublime Text, there should be a way to keep the preferences without needing to ignore updates. But I am going to keep it that way until I (or someone else) finds a better solution.